# Linear model decomposition

Tags: r, regression, logistic, logit, descriptive-statistics

Is is possible to decompose fitted linear model? What I mean by that:

I have parameters of fitted linear model as following:

```
y=2.3a-1.23b+1.65c+1.76d
```

Now I have (known) all variables `a,b,c,d`

How to obtain the net effect (contribution) of each individual variable?

Let's say that y (after pre-multiplying with variables `a,b,c,d` I get `y=34,324`.
I would like to get the contribution (effect) of variable i.e. `d` so that I can plot
y~d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for either an added-variable plot or a component-plus-residual plot. If you're using R, the **car** and **effects** packages offer several ways of displaying these.

Comment: Never used these component plus residual plots before. These are great!

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm using also R!I would need the same for survival (cox) model, which is non-linear, how to approach it in this case? Thanks.

Comment: The answer is here: http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/084bsmm9m8/r-added-variable-plot-for-cox-regression

Comment: I'm really surprised this answer got so many upvotes. You should at least mention the relevant functions and show some examples. `car` package contains almost 100 different functions...

Comment: See [What does an Added Variable Plot (Partial Regression Plot) explain in a multiple regression?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/125561/17230).